# Schlage Locks - What is "Less Full Sized Core" vs Full Size?

Tags: lock

I am buying a Schlage commercial lock set, and there is a $120 price delta between:

[FSIC Full Size Inter-changeable Cores](https://commercial.schlage.com/en/products/key-systems/fsic-full-size-interchangeable-cores.html)

And

Less Full Sized Core

What does this mean?

Answer (score 4):

"Less" here means "without". You can purchase the lock set either including the core, or with a hole where you can add a core you already have or one you purchase separately.

Comment: "Less" as in "minus". A bit awkward in this instance, but not entirely uncommon in modern English usage. "Your total, less the 10% 'friend' discount is...".

Comment: Got it. If it said "Less Core" I would track it better. "Less Full Size Core" confused me. Thanks all!